# Aligning horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4ac69ab/)

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}

.child {
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.circle {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #0F0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 25%;
    position: relative;
}
```

I have n divs. And I have `100%` width. I want to align divs horizontally centered. Number of divs in a row is based on the size of the div.

If I set size of `child` div `250px`, then for eg, if screen width is `1000px`, only 3 divs should be horizontally placed.[Because margin between divs must be considered] And left, right spacing must be equal.

I am not able to come up with a general solution. Any suggestions?

I am trying to design responsive divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/n4jp7feh/)

CSS:

```
.container{
  text-align:center; /* add this */

.child{
  display:inline-block; /*instead of float:left */
```

> The text-align CSS property describes how *inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element*. text-align does not control the alignment of block elements, only their ***inline content***.
>
> [MDN - CSS:text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

Because we have the content `display:inline-block` they are considered as inline content thus the `text-align` will center its content

While the `float` property "*specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the **left** or **right** side of its container*"

Comment: Can you please explain how does added property helps to achieve the desired solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with **Flexbox**

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child{
  flex: 0 0 75px;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle{
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #0F0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="child"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="child"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="child"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="child"><div class="circle"></div></div>
</div>
```

Or if you want equal space between divs you can use [`justify-content: space-around;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child{
  flex: 0 0 75px;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle{
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #0F0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="child"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="child"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="child"><div class="circle"></div></div>
  <div class="child"><div class="circle"></div></div>
</div>
```